# Check if variable exists and is zero in eperl

Tags: perl, variables

I am trying to expand a file using eperl which has a section like this:

```
<: if (defined($variable) && ($variable =~ 0)) { :>//
print "XYZ\n";
<: } else { :>//
print "ABC\n";
<: } :>//
```

For cases where the variable is not defined or is set to 1 I want to print ABC. But this doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: I could not get eperl `Parse::ePerl` - http://search.cpan.org/~rse/eperl-2.2.13/mod/Parse/ePerl.pm - to build on my system...could it be that you just need more `<:` lines?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used (or even heard of) "ePerl" until just now, but it looks like a templating language of sorts. Assuming that the embedded Perl is just normal Perl, I'd change `$variable =~ 0` to a simple `$variable == 0`. No need for a regex there, and you're missing the regex start/end delimiters anyway.